# How to get the tag and store the data from other tags inside the parent?

Tags: xcode, ios7, xml-parsing

My XML file is shown below

```xml
<NotifyInfo>
    <NotifyCount>5</NotifyCount>
    <Notify>
        <title>News/Notices</title>
        <count>1</count>
        <url>notice_board.jsp</url>
    </Notify>
    <Notify>
        <title>Results</title>
        <count>2</count>
        <url>reports.jsp</url>
    </Notify>
    <Notify>
        <title>Photo Gallery</title>
        <count>2</count>
        <url>photo_slider.jsp</url>
    </Notify>
</NotifyInfo>
```

I want to get the `<Notify></Notify>` tags and store each value i.e, title, count and url of each notify, in order to call that value in my project whenever it is needed.

I already used `XMLReader` class and I am getting all other tag values using this but when there are repeated tags inside a parent tag I don't know how to parse the data.

Comment: Thanks Peh. Finally figure it out using NSXMLParser. http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/xmlparsing-with-nsxmlparser-tutorial